выдает ошибку ранер такую вот при стадии building - Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password
вот сам текст пайплайна
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

# Этап сборки Docker образа
build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    # Вход в Docker Hub
    - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
    # Сборка Docker образа
    - docker build -t my-image:latest .
    # Тегирование и публикация образа на Docker Hub
    - docker tag my-image:latest $DOCKER_USERNAME/polearis:latest
    - docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/polearis:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

# Этап тестирования
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests..."

# Этап развертывания
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying..."


пароль  и имя много раз перепроверял, я настраивал эти переменные в найстройках CI/CD  может ли быть ошибка в чем-то другом по вашему опыту или все таки неправильно данные указал?

